# Can I update an attribute even if the model is invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible in rails to update the model e.g. name, even if the model in the database is invalid e.g.  is missing email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [**`rails methods which skip validations`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations). In your case you can either use [`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute) or [`update_column`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column)